# Is there a way to automatically add a query parameter to all WordPress Post URLS?

Tags: wordpress

I am needing to add some additional 'get' parameters to all WordPress posts by default and am unsure how best to do it. E.g. example.com/george?s=default

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can url [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) action to do so:

```
function append_param_redirect(){
   if ( is_main_query() ) {
      $location = esc_url(add_query_arg('s', 'default'));
      wp_redirect($location);
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'append_param_redirect');
```

Comment: I used this method, however it now doesn't display any thing. 

No Results Found
The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post.